# Is there something in C# that is similar with java.lang.Class?

Tags: c#, class, runtime

For example, I want to dynamically tell a Jason converter which type of Class it should deserialize into. In Java, I can use java.lang.Class. Is there an equivalent concept in C#?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx

Comment: if you google `c# java.lang.class`, you'll find [this](http://www.emu.edu.tr/aelci/Courses/D-318/D-318-Files/C%20Sharp%20From%20a%20Java%20Developer's%20Perspective.htm) in the first page

Comment: If you Google `C# equivalent of java.lang.class`, this StackOverflow question is the first hit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most serializers have either a generic API or a `Type`-based API; both are applicable here. For example, json.net offers both:

```
var foo = (Foo) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Foo));
```

and

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
```

It is the first that is *most similar* to what you describe; the key here is the `Type`:

```
Type type = typeof(Foo);
```

There are other ways of getting a `Type` instance, of course, including by-name, and generic construction:

```
Type itemType = someAssembly.GetType("My.Magic.Type");
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
```

which results in the `Type` representing `List<My.Magic.Type>`. Note that in .NET, generics *exist as a first-class runtime feature* - they aren't removed by the compiler via type erasure.